# Jersey @HeaderParam null in POST

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jetty

I'm getting NULL @HeaderParam in my resource on a POST. However, Authentication filter intercepts the call before it reaches to the resource and successfully extracts header info. Same header info. turns out null in resource.

It is failing in constructor and throwing NullPointerException.

Code of resource class:

```
@Path("/profile")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserAccountEP {

    @HeaderParam("userId")
    public String userId;

    public UserAccountEP()
    {
        if(userId==null)
            throw new NullPointerException("UserId is null");
    }


    @POST
    @Path("/action")
    public void action(String ip) throws IOException {}
```

}

Can someone please look into what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injection takes place after the class is constructed, so you can't access injected values inside the constructor.

Use @PostConstruct to annotate a callback method like shown below.

```
@PostConstruct
private void validate() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: So, is there any listener for injection which I can use to validate injected values? Thanks though.